# Setting input name for a dynamically created input box

Tags: jquery, html, node.js

I have a form where users can click a button and add as many input box as they want on demand.

Since all input boxes are of the same style I decided to just append the input box to the form by doing something like this:

```
 $(".addParts").click(function(e){
        e.preventDefault();
        $(".fieldsWrapper").append('<div class ="row no-gutters partsBorder"><div class="col-4"><div class="row no-gutters"><div class="col-1"><button class="btn btn-danger delete" type="button"><a href="#" class="delete">X</a></button></div><div class="col"><input name="partNumber" class="typeahead parts form-control" type="text" id="partNumberInput" aria-describedby="enter Part Number" placeholder="Part Number"></div></div></div>')
    })
```

Since the input box all have the same name, is there a way to collect the value from all the input box in my Nodejs backend?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Yes, you can just name the inputbox to array. Like, `name[]`.

```
<input name="partNumber[]" class="typeahead parts form-control" type="text" id="partNumberInput" aria-describedby="enter Part Number" placeholder="Part Number">
```

Now, you can access the values using,

```
const parts = req.body.partNumber
```

Make sure you are using urlencoded bodyParser support:

```
app.use(bodyParser.urlencoded({ extended: true }));
```